# databases - manage products part of products in business management software

Tags: database, business-intelligence

in my company's business management software, I manage the products this way:

table **products**

```
id  name        part_of_id  ...
1   license     NULL
2   computer    NULL
3   computer    2
4   keyboard    2
5   mouse       2
```

table **customer_invoices**

```
id  ...
1
2
```

table **customer_invoice_products**

```
product_id  invoice_id  price   ...
1           1           100
2           2           300
```

table **supplier_invoices**

```
id  ...
1
2
```

table **supplier_invoice_products**

```
product_id  invoice_id  price   ...
1           1           90
3           2           250
4           2           10
5           2           10
```

1st example, we buy 1 license from the supplier and sell it to the customer, everything is fine

2nd example, we buy 1 computer, 1 keyboard, 1 mouse from the supplier and sell them as 1 computer to the customer, the problems are if e.g. I need to search for all the products related to an order I have to query for all the products directly related to it (product id 1) and for all the products related to them (products id 2, 3 and 4)

apart from obviously selling the computer to the customer as 3 products, is there a better way to do this and what are best practices to manage this?

Comment: Customers and orders data model: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/customers_and_orders/index.htm

Comment: there is no supplier_orders_products table, the question is what if customer's products and supplier's products doesn't match?

Comment: Quote: " is there a better way to do this and what are best practices to manage this?"  That's the question I answered.  Order fulfillment has been analyzed many times.

Comment: yes, but I already use that model, my problem is about the management of products part of products as in the 2nd example